# Keep getting 'dispatch' undefined with redux-promise

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, redux-promise

I am really new to Redux and its concepts, especially middleware so I do apologise for any stupid errors.

In this project of mine, I need to use redux-thunk. I've looked at a few guides and explanations on how to apply them. I then kept receiving an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined". I opened developer tools and got shown this error:

[image]

I have no idea if I am doing anything right. Below are the codes for my action creators and store.

*actions/index.js*

```
import axios from 'axios';

export function fetchLessons() {
  console.log('called!');
  return function(dispatch) {
    axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/lessons`)
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch(fetchLessonsSuccess(response))
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch(fetchLessonsError(err))
      })
  }
}

function fetchLessonsError(){
  return "An error has occured";
}

function fetchLessonsSuccess(response) {
  return {
    type: FETCH_LESSONS,
    payload: request
  };
}
```

*index.js(store)*

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import rootReducer from './reducers/index';
import routes from './routes';
import promise from 'redux-promise';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const middleware = applyMiddleware(promise(), thunk);
const store = createStore(rootReducer, compose(middleware));

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your call to `applyMiddleware()` is slightly off.  You want to pass the imported promise middleware directly, not call it: `applyMiddleware(promise, thunk)`.

That function is basically a factory.  Redux will call it and pass in the store's `dispatch` function, which the middleware can then use to dispatch actions whenever it's ready.

Answer (score 0):

i am not totally sure but something like this

```
export function fetchLessons() {
  console.log('called!');
  return function(dispatch) {
    return dispatch({
      type: 'FETCH_LESSONS',
      payload: axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/lessons`)
        .then((response) => {
          dispatch(fetchLessonsSuccess(response))
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          dispatch(fetchLessonsError(err))
        });
    });
  };
}

function fetchLessonsError(){
  return "An error has occured";
}

function fetchLessonsSuccess(response) {
  return {
    type: 'FETCH_LESSONS_FULFILLED',
    payload: response
  };
}
```